# Characters not colored in HTML fragment

Tags: html, css, colors

The Unicode block characters in this HTML fragment aren't being colored in the way I expect:

```html
<div style="display: inline-grid; grid-template-columns: 1; grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr">
  <span style="min-width: 1em; min-height: 1ex; color: rgb(255, 0,
  0)">█</span>
  <span style="min-width: 1em; min-height: 1ex; color: rgb(0, 255,
  0)">█</span>
  <span style="min-width: 1em; min-height: 1ex; color: rgb(0, 0,
  255)">█</span>
  <span style="min-width: 1em; min-height: 1ex; color: rgb(128, 128,
  128)">█</span>
  <span>╲</span>
</div>
```

I've tried this in both Chrome and Edge.

The four block characters are meant to be colored but are rendering as white.  When I examine each element in developer mode, the CSS properties panel shows the right colors, but not the rendering.

What's going on and how do I make this work?

Comment: Works fine on Google Chrome Version 105.0.5195.127 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 11 Pro.

Comment: And Microsoft Edge Version 105.0.1343.50 (Official build) (64-bit) on Windows 11 Pro.

Comment: Seems to be working for me on Firefox version 105.0.1 (64-bit) on Windows 11 Home.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  I should have mentioned before that for readability i use a dark theme.  In the case of Edge, it picks that up from Windows.  I don't recallhow I did that in Chrome.

Comment: Ive given up on making this work as HTML.  Since it's kind of a graphic anyway, I made it work in SVG.